# Using related_name correctly in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models that are related together using ForeignKey and related_name is used. Here is an example.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True)


class Class(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,
                                related_name='classes',
                                null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

For example, I would like to access the class name.

This is what i tried.

```
john = Student.objects.get(username = 'john')
print john.classes.name
```

nothing's get printed.

But when i try `john.classes`

i get django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x109911410. This is shows that they are related. But i would like to get the class name.

Am i doing something wrong? How do i access the name of the class using related_name? Need some guidance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, classes is a manager. It can be several classes for one teacher. So to output their names you should do:

```
john = Student.objects.get(username='john')
for class2 in john.classes.all():
   print class2.name
```

If you want only one class for one student then use one-to-one relation. In this case you can access the related field with your method.

Comment: there is only one class for each child. then why not john.classes.name?

Comment: your solution works but like to know why john.classes.name is not working?

Comment: Because ForeignKey makes several classes for one child, not one class. If you want only one class the use onetoone field.

Comment: @lakesh I've changed my answer.

Comment: another question: since unicode of class returns self.name how can i use that? it can't be used together with related_name? if possible, how do i do it?

Comment: When you try to output john.classes you will see john.classes.name as a result (if you have changed to one-to-one relation). And you will see the name in Django admin as a name for objects of the 'Class' class.

Comment: if i didn't change to one-to-one relation? how do i do it? is it possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15708/discussion-between-sergzach-and-lakesh)

Answer (score 3):

Just be aware: you are defining a 1-many relationship. Thus, student could have multiple classes, therefore john.classes.name cannot work, since you have not specified the class of which you want to have the name. in john.classes "classes" is just a manager that you can use like any other Django Model Manager. You can do a john.classes.all() (like sergzach propsed), but also things like john.classes.get(...) or john.classes.filter(...).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this to access the first row in the table

```
john = Student.objects.get(username = 'john')    
john.classes.all().first().name # to access first row
john.classes.all().last().name # to access last row
```

in the above example you don't want to iterate over the objects

it will give you the name of the class in the first row